# Is it possible to generate TSV files in bulk each of which grabbing all the data inside correlative columns within one spreadsheet tab?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good morning.
I have a Sheet tab called "Tsv Export" containing 16 columns of data.
I'd like to export all these 16 columns each on a separated tsv file.
If possible, each tsv file should be named as the corresponding exported column number (ex  01.tsv, 02.tsv etc)
The 16 tsv files should be saved in the same drive folder where the Sheets document is located.
Note: the script might support more columns, not just 16, and stop the loop at the first empty column.

Thanks so much

Comment: I proposed a sample script for your goal. Could you please confirm it? But I'm worry about my understanding for the one column TSV file. So if my understanding was not correct and this sample was not the direction you expect, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample TSV file you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it and modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the sheet "Tsv Export" and export each column as the TSV file.
- You want to give the value of index + 1 as the filename.
- You want to export the file to the same folder with the Spreadsheet.
- When the column without no values is retrieved at the loop, you want to stop the script.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer? In this answer, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Retrieve the folder.
2. Retrieve values from sheet of "Tsv Export";
3. Transpose the retrieved values.
4. Export each column as the TSV file.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Tsv Export";
  
  // 1. Retrieve the folder.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const folder = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next();
  
  // 2. Retrieve values from sheet of "Tsv Export";
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  // 3. Transpose the retrieved values.
  const converted = values[0].map((_, i) => values.map(r => r[i]));
  
  // 4. Export each column as the TSV file.
  for (let i = 0; i < converted.length; i++) {
    const v = converted[i];
    if (v.every(e => !e)) {
      break;
    } else {
      folder.createFile(`${('0' + (i + 1)).slice(-2)}.tsv`, v.join("\n"), "text/tab-separated-values");
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- Please confirm the sheet name again.
- When you want to export a column to a row as TSV format, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      folder.createFile(`${('0' + (i + 1)).slice(-2)}.tsv`, v.join("\n"), "text/tab-separated-values");
    ```
  - To

    ```
      folder.createFile(`${('0' + (i + 1)).slice(-2)}.tsv`, v.join("\t"), "text/tab-separated-values");
    ```
- Please use this script with V8.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getparents)
- [createFile(name, content, mimeType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfilename,-content,-mimetype)